# CSS visibility rules

Tags: css, html-rendering

I tried searching for this on Google, but to no avail.

Can someone point me to a good resource that explains the rendering and visibility rules for CSS ? Or if it is very simple, can someone please write it down here ?

To give you an example, let's say that I have 2 large divs, `DIV_LARGE1`, `DIV_LARGE2`, that are not contained within each other and a small div, `DIV_SMALL`. When `DIV_SMALL` is defined within `DIV_LARGE1`, I can see that part of it which falls inside `DIV_LARGE1`, but the area that is shared with `DIV_LARGE2` gets hidden beneath `DIV_LARGE2`. I am displaying `DIV_SMALL` (by setting its `display:inline`) after the page has rendered (on some click), so it should not matter that `DIV_LARGE2` comes after `DIV_LARGE1` in the HTML code.

What takes precedence over what ? Since my smaller div has `position:relative` and both the other divs (`DIV_LARGE*`) have `position:absolute`, I can infer that absolute positioning takes precedence over relative if the div is not defined inside it. But is this correct ? What are the precise rules ?

Comment: I think an HTML structure (with any relevant CSS) would be much easier to visualize than a paragraph of text.

Comment: Some [jsFiddle demos](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful as well.

Comment: I think you are talking about [z-index](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp) though I'm not pretty sure if I'm right :)

Comment: Add raw html/css. This paragraph is brutal to read.

Comment: putting up code modified to make it simple is brutal for me. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phelios is correct, the issue you're running into is related to the z-index property.
Here's a great article from SmashingMag that explains it in detail: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

For the tl;dr - positioned elements get stacked in the order they're placed in the html code, so your div_small inside the first large div is by default always going to be stacked "under" the second large div. You can fix this by setting the small div's z-index property in css.

Comment: yeah. i solved the problem by doing that. so, u r saying that if a div is after another one in the html code, then the 2nd div will always cover the first one, even if we make the 1st one appear after the whole page is loaded ?

Comment: yes, essentially stacking order is based solely on the order of the elements in the code. if you make a new div "appear" after loading the page, say through javascript, the browser will still render the page based on where the new div is placed. using floats and relative positioning is the way to get around this, so you can move elements that are semantically later in the code to an "earlier" location on the page.